# Movie about trying to stop global warming but caused ice age on accident

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw a movie on Syfi channel about 15 years ago. It was about scientists trying to stop global warming, but overdo it and accidentally cause a new ice age instead.

I can’t remember the name of it. Does anyone know what movie it was?

Comment: Except for being human caused, this could be [The Day After Tomorrow](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0319262/).

Comment: @DavidW That [was](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Day_After_Tomorrow#Plot) caused by humans

Comment: @Punintended It was an unexpected consequence of global warming, not a deliberate attempt to reverse the effects thereof.

Comment: Do you remember any other details about the movie? Was it set while scientists were trying to stop global warming or completely after they had caused the ice age? Who were the main characters and what were they trying to accomplish? Do you remember any scenes?

Comment: This wasn't 15 years ago, but The Colony has a similar plot point. "By 2045, humans have built weather machines to control the warming climate due to climate change and global warming. The machines break down when one day it begins to snow and doesn't stop. Whatever humans remain live in underground bunkers to escape the extreme cold." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Colony_(2013_film)

Comment: It was either Snowpiercer or the colony. I’m going to have to watch them both now!  Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 2):

Snowpiercer comes to mind. (Though it was 7 years ago and not 15)

https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1706620/